# Can you assign a NULL pointer variable to a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, linked-list, null, null-pointer, minmax-heap

So I was working on the Max Heap Tree with link representation on C++.
Since I cannot upload the code as it is pretty long but while I was debugging I realized that
the execution will stop at the expression where it assgins Null pointer to a pointer.
for example

```
// if node->left_child->right_chile == NULL
node->right_child = node->left_child->right_child; // the program will exit here.
```

This kind of operation often occurs in my code at the deletion method so I was also wondering if I assign NULL variable multiple times, it causes error.
for example in continuition of above example,

```
node->parent->left_child = node->right_child;
```

I was trying to figure out how NULL pointer behaves but I cannot quite get it.
Could you please help me?

Comment: "I cannot upload the code as it is pretty long" thats why you should post a [mcve]. Posting your complete code is rarely the right thing to do. Please follow the link and read about it

Comment: Most probably, `node->left_child == NULL` that is why it can not further access it's right child and simply throws an error.

Comment: Compile with -fsanitize=address, so you can see more detail of the error. It's probably due to you dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Tip: In C++ you should be using `nullptr` instead of C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: There is no guarantee by the C++ standard that the program will exit at that point.  It's probably running into **undefined behavior** dereferencing a `nullptr`, and then the operating system has memory address `0x0000` trip a segv (violation trying to access an inaccessible segment).

Answer (score 2):

> Can you assign a NULL pointer variable to a pointer variable?

Yes. You can assign a pointer to another as long as the value of the that is assigned from has been initialised. If that value is null, it is OK. For example, this is fine:

```
Node* a = nullptr;
Node* b = nullptr;
a = b;
```

> ```
> node->right_child = node->left_child->right_child; // the program will exit here.
> ```

This implies that one of `node` or `node->left_child` is probably not a valid pointer. Either of those would result in undefined behaviour.

---

P.S. Don't use the `NULL` macro in C++. It has bee obsoleted by `nullptr`.